# define function as a result of gradient returns unexpected result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

This is probably very simple problem, but what am i doing wrong?

```
c[x_, y_] := x*y;
Grad[c[x, y], {x, y}]
d[x_, y_] := Grad[c[x, y], {x, y}];
d[1, 1]
```

Returns:

```
{y, x}
Grad[1,{1, 1}]
```

The first is obviously correct, the second one, I have no idea why it returns this nonsense.

Comment: Easy work-around: `With[{g=Grad[c[x, y], {x, y}]}, d[x_, y_] := g];`

Comment: @b3m2a1 This is incorrect… just check `?d`.

Comment: @xzczd ah looks like it localized `x` and `y` before evaluation. Wasn't sure if it'd do that before the injection or after this works: `With[{g=Grad[c[x, y], {x, y}]}, SetDelayed@@HoldAllComplete[d[x_, y_] ,  g]]` but is no longer as "simple"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `d` replaces the *variables* in `Grad` before it evaluates the actual gradient (e.g. `d[1, 1] -> Grad[c[1, 1], {1, 1}]`).  A workaround is as simple as making the assignment immediate instead of delayed.

```
d[x_, y_] = Grad[c[x, y], {x, y}];
d[1, 1]
```

> {1, 1}

If we take a look at the [`DownValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) of `d`, we can `d` is what we want it to be.

```
DownValues@d
```

> {HoldPattern[d[x_, y_]] :> {y, x}}